# How to use Inline method in FDT width AirSDK3.6?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, inline, fdt

In Air3.6, as3 supports Inline and threads. In FlashBuilder I set "-inline" and the project will compile successfull, but In FDT, It doesn't work, how to use Inline Method In FDT? 
thanks.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work? What does the console say about your compiler arguments?

Comment: Because it's couldn't be compiled, but I use "-swf-verstion=17" then the "Worker Class" could be compiled successfully.

Comment: I followed the steps on http://fdt.powerflasher.com/2012/12/how-to-install-asc-2-0-in-fdt/ , but I can't see the  ASC 2.0 option in launcher. Is it a fdt version problem?